# Executing Node.js file from outside the folder breaks file path

Tags: bash, node.js, file-io

I have a Node.js file called "server.js".

In the script, I am opening some files using something like:

```
var certPem = fs.readFileSync('cert_and_key_dev.pem', encoding='ascii');
```

Using the bash shell, if I cd into the directory where the server.js is, and run the command:

> [mybashshell]$ node server.js

It works, I got no error. Server launches and runs.

Now when I cd OUT OF the directory where the server.js file is, then run the same shell command again to launch my server.

It complains about my file path to my "cert_and_key_dev.pem" being broken.

I wasn't expecting something like this to happen. I though the path used in the script file being executed should be relative to the script file, not to the location where I executed my bash shell command.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put this at the beginning of your script.

```
process.chdir(__dirname);
```

This will change the process's working directory into the directory path of the file (`__dirname`) being executed.

For more information on the function read [this](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory).

Comment: Is there any benefits between this method vs the method given by chbrown ? I'm curious about which is the more proper way.

Comment: It really depends on the purpose.  If you are running more of a "server", I would suggest changing into `__dirname`.  If you were running a folder upload script, for example, I would suggest to use chbrown's code.  You have to weigh out how often you plan to use the current working directory path over the current script's directory path.

Answer (score 7):

Or

```
var path = require('path');
var key = path.join(__dirname, 'cert_and_key_dev.pem');
var certPem = fs.readFileSync(key, encoding='ascii');
```

If you don't want to `cd` for whatever reason.

Comment: LOL, thanks guys, they both work but I don't know which one to accept, wish I can give tick both answers. I'll give it to Julian Lannigan since he answered first and could use the rep boost (hope you don't mind chbrown).

Comment: When in doubt, the less code wins. If you don't need to know what directory you started your script from, Julian's answer is better.

Comment: But do remember Zhang, that you can always store the current working directory in a variable before changing it. Call `process.cwd()`